# Check if socket is ready to send and receive

Tags: python, sockets

python socket . check if server send me heloo message

in python socket  i open socket connection

and it is good  how check if connected or not ?

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bind = '0.0.0.0'
lport = self.get_free_port()
host = (str(ip), int(rport))
sock.settimeout(15)
sock.connect(host)
```

Comment: When `sock.connect` returns without raising an error, you are connected. `sock.connect_ex` is a bit different - it includes an error return. But if the return code is zero, you are connected.

Comment: it is connected and on send data it is send with our error but on recived it is timeout

Comment: That means the server didn't return anything.

Comment: what sendto() return if send is good ?

Comment: I need to backtrack on previous comments - I didn't realize this is a datagram socket. The connect only records the target address with the kernel for that socket. No data is sent and the computer on the other side has no idea anything happened. sendto will put the dgram in the kernel's queue but it could be dropped if the target address is invalid or nothing is listening on the port. A recv will only work if the other side knows to send you some data.